# Ionic qrcode generator

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-input type="text" placeholder="My Qr Data" [(ngModel)]="qrData"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <button ion-button full (click)="createCode()"><ion icon name="barcode"></ion>Create Code</button>
    <button ion-button full (click)="scanCode()"><ion icon name="qr-scanner"></ion>Scan Code</button>

    <ion-card *ngIf="createdCode">
      <ngx-qrcode [qrc-value]="createdCode"></ngx-qrcode>
      <ion-card-content>
        <p>Value : {{createdCode}}</p>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>

    <ion-card *ngIf="scannedCode">
      <ion-card-content>
        Result from Scan: {{scannedCode}}
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
```

Homepage.ts

```
 qrData= null;
    createdCode=null;
    scannedCode=null;
  constructor(private BarcodeScanner:BarcodeScanner) {

  }
  createCode(){
      this.createdCode =this.qrData;
  }

  scanCode(){
      this.BarcodeScanner.scan().then(barcodeData => {
        this.scannedCode = barcodeData.text;
      })
```

I am using the qr code generator but it shows the value as text? I can't see it as qr code. Displays the generated Code as text

Comment: can you please share what error you are getting in your console

Comment: it seems like `npm i ngx-qrcode2 –save` you forgot to install this module.